# Would it be okay to try to reverse engineer Spore as an experiment and publish the results on-line?

Tags: software-engineering, legal

Game in question is Spore. I'm fascinated by space and this game has been my favorite for years.

Now, I would try to reverse engineer as much as I can as an experiment because I am interested in generally how game works under the hood. On example what steganography algorithm is used to hide models in pictures or algorithm for generating planets and solar systems etc... I can think of a million different things.

But, some of my wishes are also to put this reverse engineered code public on my GitHub as my work. I don't know if this would be okay legally and if it wouldn't create some type of a problem because I put my work public.

Of course there is a rule that sometimes you cannot fully reverse engineer something, especially something like a game this big and code wouldn't be 100% equal as the source. But again, this is something to ask before even starting. It would be something really interesting, that's something I know for sure.

Comment: This is probably more of a question for https://law.stackexchange.com. But the answer is probably that you can reverse-engineer the code but you can't publish the reverse-engineered code, because that would be a copyright violation.

Comment: What does the Terms of Use and/or the End User Legal Agreement of the game say about it?

Comment: Yeah, that's where my plan for this to go public goes under. From the user agreement it's mentioned that any service or product must not be reverse engineered or extracted data from.

Comment: Then I suppose you have your answer. As Philipp said, I suppose you could do it privately and not publish the results. I'm not condoning reverse engineering, I'm just saying that it would be hard for anyone to know about it. FWIW, though, since you generally don't want to _copy_ a game but _create your own_ or _improve upon_ another game, it's generally more useful to figure out of a way _you_ could do it in _your own_ context rather than how _they_ did do it in _their own_ context.

Comment: Hm, yeah. Interesting idea. Thanks everyone!

Comment: And by the way, the "steganography to hide models in pictures" becomes actually a lot less impressive when you look at the specification of the PNG format and realize that it supports an unlimited amount of ancillary `tEXt` chunks which can contain arbitrary data without affecting how the image is rendered in an image viewer.

Comment: @Philipp I think the reason they went for steganography was so that the data would be preserved even if you, say, posted your creature image on a blogging or social media platform for others to download. These platforms frequently strip out metadata, so hiding the needed information in the image data increased the number of ways it could be shared successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From the user agreement it's mentioned that any service or product must not be reverse engineered or extracted data from.

Then no, it's not OK.

As luck would have it, this story just crossed my feed today: [Revealing *Mortal Kombat II* Code Leak Pulled by Warner Bros.](https://kotaku.com/mortal-kombat-2-mk2-source-code-leak-dmca-takedown-1849977045)

It describes a situation where a user uploaded *Mortal Kombat II*'s source code to GitHub:

> The lawyers at Warner Bros. took exception to this by issuing a swift DMCA takedown notice that Github (sic) adhered to by disabling public access

So even a game significantly older than *Spore* still has the intellectual property rights to its source code protected by copyright law; that protection is actively enforced by corporate legal teams, and GitHub will cooperate with those measures.

Even if your reverse engineering efforts produce code that is not identical to the original source code, I'd wager that's not a fight you want to pick with a legal team the size of EA's.